# Connection timed out

Tags: mercadopago, drupal, timeout

Hace varios meses tengo en un sitio hecho en ***Drupal CMS*** el módulo ***Mercado Pago Payment*** funcionando correctamente. Sin embargo, en los últimos días estoy teniendo un ***timeout*** al invocar el método `create_preference($preference)` utilizando la ***versión 0.5.2*** de la librería. Esto ocurre de manera intermitente.

Haciendo un ping desde el servidor hacia **api.mercadopago.com** obtengo:

```
PING api.mercadopago.com (54.82.133.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-54-82-133-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.82.133.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=236 time=160 ms
64 bytes from ec2-54-82-133-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.82.133.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=236 time=160 ms
64 bytes from ec2-54-82-133-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.82.133.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=236 time=159 ms
```